# Prevent Reavers from dealing splash damage to friendly and allied units

Tags: level-design, modding, starcraft

Just for fun I made some games in the Starcraft Broodwar map editor (scdraft2.0).

I notice that in my map Reavers deal damage to friendly and allied units as well as to neutral units. It's a cat and mouse map so when friendly units kill your teammates it's not fun.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: In my opinion questions about modding a particular game aren't a good fit for the gamedev stack exchange. I'm voting to close as off topic. I think mod forums dedicated to modding Starcraft would be a better place to ask this question.

Comment: @Byte56 Most recent meta discussion about whether modding is on-topic was here: http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/58/do-mod-and-map-making-questions-belong-here  That discussion is more than two years old, though, and maybe should be revisited in light of gamedev's changing policies in other areas.

Comment: @TrevorPowell Thanks, looks like the community decided it's on topic. I would be interested in bringing it up again on meta, I may do that soon.

Comment: @Byte56 yea I didnt think those kind of questions were a good fit for this website either, until moderators from arqade migrated my question here telling me that it is on topic and that's where i should post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to disable the reaver's friendly splash damage except through modding.  For your map, you may just have to accept that reavers will be able to hurt friendly units and re-balance your other units accordingly.  Alternatively, you could just avoid using reavers in your map.